# Smooth Animation with Python Turtle Graphics and Stamps

Tags: python, animation, turtle-graphics

Is it possible to get a smoother animation effect using Turtle Graphics and the `stamp()` method than what the code below gives?

One attempt I made was to only clear the first stamp using `stamper.clearstamps(1)` inside `move_blocks`, and to only draw the new block each time, but the result looked the same. I think the problem might be that stamping calls `Screen.update()` in the background, although I haven't confirmed this.

```
import turtle


def move_blocks():
    stamper.clearstamps()
    new_block = blocks[-1].copy()
    new_block[0] += 20
    if new_block[0] > 250:
        new_block[0] = - 250
    blocks.append(new_block)
    blocks.pop(0)

    for block in blocks:
        stamper.goto(block[0], block[1])
        stamper.stamp()

    screen.update()
    turtle.ontimer(move_blocks, 100)


screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.tracer(0)  # Turn off automatic animation

stamper = turtle.Turtle("square")
stamper.penup()

blocks = [[0, 0], [20, 0], [40, 0], [60, 0]]

for block in blocks:
    stamper.goto(block[0], block[1])
    stamper.stamp()

move_blocks()
turtle.done()
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the problem might be that stamping calls Screen.update() in
> the background, although I haven't confirmed this.

This appears to be true, and is easily confirmed, but not necessarily the whole problem.  Below is my rework of your code to optimize it by removing only the defunct stamp ID, but it looks no better than yours.  You can see I've commented out `screen.update()` which makes no difference:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def move_blocks():
    new_block = blocks.pop(0)
    new_block[0] = blocks[-1][0] + 20

    if new_block[0] > 250:
        new_block[0] = -250

    blocks.append(new_block)

    stamper.goto(new_block)
    stamper.clearstamp(ids.pop(0))
    ids.append(stamper.stamp())

    # screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move_blocks, 100)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.tracer(0)  # Turn off automatic animation

stamper = Turtle('square')
stamper.hideturtle()
stamper.penup()

blocks = [[0, 0], [20, 0], [40, 0], [60, 0]]
ids = []

for block in blocks:
    stamper.goto(block)
    ids.append(stamper.stamp())

# screen.update()

move_blocks()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Trying to be clever, I wanted to do a comparison of *drawing* vs. *stamping* but the result is the same, the fill operations trigger a `screen.update()` and get us right back where we started:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def move_blocks():
    filler.clear()

    new_block = blocks.pop(0)
    new_block[0] = blocks[-1][0] + 20

    if new_block[0] > 250:
        new_block[0] = -250

    blocks.append(new_block)

    for block in blocks:
        fill(block)

    # screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move_blocks, 100)

def fill(position):
    filler.goto(position)

    filler.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        filler.forward(CURSOR_SIZE)
        filler.left(90)
    filler.end_fill()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.tracer(0)  # Turn off automatic animation

filler = Turtle()
filler.hideturtle()
filler.penup()

blocks = [[0, 0], [20, 0], [40, 0], [60, 0]]

for block in blocks:
    fill(block)

# screen.update()

move_blocks()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Finally, I did an implementation that is under the control of `tracer()` and programmer initiated `screen.update()` calls.  I simply reshape the cursor and move it for comparison purposes.  You can see the difference when `screen.update()` is commented out this time.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
CURSOR_LENGTH = 80
STEP_SIZE = 1

def move():
    x = turtle.xcor() + STEP_SIZE

    if x - CURSOR_LENGTH/2 > 250:
        turtle.setx(-250 - CURSOR_LENGTH/2)
    else:
        turtle.forward(STEP_SIZE)

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move, 5 * STEP_SIZE)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.tracer(0)  # Turn off automatic animation

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.shapesize(stretch_len=CURSOR_LENGTH/CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.penup()

screen.update()

move()

screen.exitonclick()
```

However, this implementation points out that the earlier poor visual performance is also due to a large step size -- if you change `STEPSIZE = CURSOR_SIZE`, then you have the same step size, and the same performance, as your original.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd love to know more about your interest in Turtle Graphics - you seem to be a true aficionado and maestro, which is quite rare. do you have any books, blogs,  repos etc. please?